# Update problem with "Failed to fetch" error

Tags: updates

I don't get Firefox 7 update. When I try to check for updates from update manager, I get:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://wine.budgetdedicated.com/apt/dists/edgy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/edgy/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.170 80]
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Any idea?

Comment: it looks like that your asking for the package's from ubuntu 6.10 are you using 6.10?

Comment: No, I'm using 11.04. And I expect firefox to be updated to version 7.0. Since it's not, I tried to update manually. I don't know if this error have something to do with it.

Comment: Seeings that it's answered I won't have do it I saw that repository was from ubuntu 6.10 which isn't there any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a Wine and Ubuntu repository from five years ago. So yeah, that won't work anymore. ;)

It's a fairly innocuous problem. Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` with administrator privileges and remove the lines with 'dists/edgy/' in them. Or leave them there, shouldn't matter.

In any case, none of this is affecting Firefox. F7 will land when it lands.

Comment: I got update today.